# jsreport page numbering in WPF app C# page index is not changing

Tags: c#, html, css, jsreport

i have this headerfooter.html code which supposed to shows footer with page numbers:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        html {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            direction: rtl;
            margin: 15px 10px 10px 15px;
        }
        .main {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 2px solid black; /* Add a border to each page */
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        .header {
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
        .footer {
            width: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {{#each $pdf.pages}}
    {{#if @index}}
    <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
    {{/if}}
    <main class="main">
        <header class="header">
        </header>
        <footer class="footer">
            <span>Page {{getPageNumber @index}} of {{getTotalPages ../$pdf.pages}}</span>
        </footer>
    </main>
    {{/each}}
</body>
</html>
```

and I use this code to render the report from the headerfooter and another HTML file containing the report data:

```
var report = await rs.RenderAsync(new RenderRequest
{
    Template = new Template
    {                       
        Content = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path.LocalPath, "ReportTemplates", _report.ReportTemplate)),
        Engine = Engine.Handlebars, // You can specify the template engine if needed
        Recipe = Recipe.ChromePdf,
        Chrome = new Chrome()
        {
            MarginBottom = "2cm",
            MarginTop = "1cm",
            MarginLeft = "1cm",
            MarginRight = "1cm"
        },
        PdfOperations = new List<PdfOperation>() {                       
        new PdfOperation{ 
        MergeWholeDocument = false,                       
        Type=PdfOperationType.Merge,
        Template=new Template{
            Helpers=File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path.LocalPath, "ReportTemplates", "helper.js")),
         Content = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path.LocalPath, "ReportTemplates", "Header-Footer.html")),
    Engine = Engine.Handlebars,
     Recipe = Recipe.ChromePdf,
        }
        }
        }
    },
    Data = _report.Content,
});
```

and this is the helper.cs code:

```
function getPageNumber(pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex == null) {
        return ''
    }
    const pageNumber = pageIndex + 1
    return pageNumber
}
function getTotalPages(pages) {
    if (!pages) {
        return '';
    }
    return pages.length;
}
```

and the report content is like this:I put divs inside content
and the content is shown and the headerfooter is also shown the only problem I am facing is page number is not shown correctly.

```
<div style='page-break-before: always;'></div>
<div class="container">
    <content/>
</div>
```

the page footer shows page 1 of 4 in all pages, the page index is not change with each page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to set:

```
 MergeWholeDocument = true
```

and the numbers are shown correctly.